# How to add custom page template to wordpress child theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to have unique css styling in wordpress. I heard about page templates, but do they work on child theme. Is it possible to create template for my page in my child themes folder?
I am using WPbakery visual composer for my content.

Is it enough to write a `page-659.php` and put it to my child-theme and build my content as simple html page or are there any other solutions, to have a part content from parent theme's templates?

How to transfer a full content from parent theme for editing in my child theme page template? My parent theme uses framework, I want to skip it, and edit raw code? Is copy source code from web a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are kinda stating the obvious... have you tried it? You seem to have the steps all figured out... and you're spot on.

Comment: I have problems with implementing it, i have tried this, and still trying, but fact is thattheme uses framework. I am not familar with it, i want to get raw code of parent themes page.php.The main problem for me is how to get/create/copy part of theme's `page.php` to my `page-569.php`.

Comment: Can you find an existing template in the parent framework, copy it to your child theme and then start customising it from there. Should be a lot easier than copying parts over. Also you can call the file anything you want `page-569.php` will only target the page with an ID of 569. 
Use this just after the first `<?php` at the top of the page to make the template selectable in your edit page screen:
`/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/`